Problem on density of a subset on $L^2([a,b],\mathbb{R})$: looking for a better solution
I have this problem that the professor gave us:
Let $\gamma ,a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $$D_{\gamma}=\{u\in C^2([a,b],\mathbb{R}):\gamma u(a)-u'(a)=0,\gamma u(b)-u'(b)=0\}$$
Prove that $D_\gamma$ is dense in $L^2([a,b];\mathbb{R})$
I think I've found a solution (still not 100% sure if it's correct):
I take $g_\delta(x)\in C^2([a,b];\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $g(x)=1$ if $x\in[a+2\delta,b-2\delta]$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x\in[a,a+\delta)\cup (b-\delta,b]$. I think this can be achieved if I "connect" the constant portion of the function with 3rd degree polynomials (in the same way I could do with lines or parabolas if I wanted $g_\delta$ to be $C^0$ or $C^1$.
Hence if I take $u\in C^2([a,b])$ I can approximate it in $L^2$ with $u_\delta(x)=g_\delta (x)u(x)$. Indeed $||u-u_\delta ||_{L^2([a,b])}=\int_a^bu(x)^2|1-g_\delta |^2\leq 16||u||^2_\infty\delta$, therefore $||u-u_\delta ||_{L^2([a,b])}\rightarrow0$ as $\delta\rightarrow 0$
I know that $C^2([a,b])$ so the proof is concluded as $u_\delta \in D_\gamma$
I feel like I've not really used the property of the set $D_\gamma $ and I think there is a better solution to this problem. Usally in exercises that we have seen in class for proving density in $L^p[a,b]$ we try to approximate $C^0_C$ or the orthogonal bases $e^{icnx}$ or $\sin(cnx)$ (where c is a constant for normalization). In this case I've tried noticing that $\phi(x)=\gamma u(x)-u'(x), u\in D_\gamma$ can be extended with periodicity and tried to approximate some orthogonal base (such as the previous one).
Can anyone help me and try to find an alternative solution that uses these properties or that is more simple?

You cannot use $|u|_{\infty}$ in your proof. You only know that $u\in L^2$.

@GReyes Yes I can, because $u\in C^2([a,b])$

Even the space $\mathscr D((a,b))$ of smooth functions with compact support in the open interval $(a,b)$ is dense in $L^2([a,b])$ and it is trivially contained in $D_\gamma$.

Consider the space $V$ of polynomials of the form $q(x)=(x-a)^2(b-x)^2p(x).$ Then $q(a)=q'(a)=q(b)=q'(b)=0,$ Hence $V\subset D.$ We claim that the space $V$ is dense in $L^2(a,b).$  Equivalently there is no nonzero function $f\in L^2(a,b)$ orthogonal to $V.$ Let $f\in L^2(a,b)$ satisfy $$\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,{q(x)}\,dx=0,\quad q\in V$$  Then $$\int\limits_a^b[(x-a)^2(b-x)^2f(x)]\,p(x)\,dx=0$$ for all polynomials $p(x).$  The polynomials are dense in $L^2(a,b),$ as they are uniformly dense in the space $C[a,b],$ which in turn is dense in $L^2(a,b).$  Thus $$(x-a)^2(b-x)^2f(x)=0$$ which implies $f=0.$
